# plot timeline chart in python without any count

Tags: python, datetime, charts, timeline

I have data something like this:

```
Id     recordDate   bodytag     recordType
123    2017-05-02   A             A1
123    2017-05-05   B             B1
123    2017-05-10   A             A1
123    2017-04-02   A             A1
234    2016-05-17   C             C1
234    2016-06-14   D             D1
234    2016-05-25   D             D1
234    2017-05-13   D             D1
234    2017-05-13   C             C1
234    2016-05-25   C             C1
234    2017-05-13   C             C1
```

Now I want to plot time line chart like, patient id 123 has on date 02/5/17 has pain in A part and has capture record A1 and on date 05/5/17 has pain in body part B so he capture record B1. for each user I want to make this kind of timeline chart.

how can I do it in python ?

So far I tried this thing

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,1))
ax.plot_date(dump['recordDate'],dump['Actual_bodyTags'])
fig.autofmt_xdate()

# everything after this is turning off stuff that's plotted by default
"""
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')

ax.get_yaxis().set_ticklabels([])
day = pd.to_timedelta("1", unit='D')
#plt.xlim(X[0] - day, X[-1] + day)
"""

plt.show()
```

and also this :

```
fig = ff.create_gantt(dump, colors=['#333F44', '#93e4c1'], index_col='Complete', show_colorbar=True,
                      bar_width=0.2, showgrid_x=True, showgrid_y=True)
py.iplot(fig, filename='gantt-use-a-pandas-dataframe', world_readable=True)
```

Comment: Maybe with `plotly`'s Gantt chart functions: https://plot.ly/python/gantt/

Comment: No one knows how to do it ?

Comment: Probably a lot of people know how to do this, but nobody wants to do this for you, without you even showing what you tried. If you first try something, look into documentation and examples, and you run into a problem, everybody is happy to help you. Show what you tried and were you are stuck...

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to just scatter plot your entries and add text to each. First the data is loaded from your text file (if you are using a standard CSV file, remove `delimiter` and `skipinitialspace`). Next it sorts the entries into a dictionary, with the keys being the `id`. For each ID it creates a separate figure. All the entries for each ID are sorted by date. If there are multiple entries for a single date, the text for them are combined vertically into a single entry to avoid overwriting. The day of the month is also added to the text.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

from itertools import groupby
from datetime import datetime
import csv

data = defaultdict(list)

with open('input2.txt', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(csv_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        row.append(datetime.strptime(row[1], '%Y-%m-%d'))
        row.append(dates.date2num(row[4]))
        data[row[0]].append(row)

bbox = dict(facecolor='blue', alpha=0.1, pad=1.0)

for rows in data.values():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 2))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    # Get date range
    d = sorted(row[5] for row in rows)
    ax.set_xlim(d[0]-10, d[-1]+10)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 0.8)

    for k, g in groupby(sorted(rows), lambda x: x[4]):
        rows = list(g)
        text = '{}\n\n{}'.format(k.day, '\n'.join([row[2] for row in rows]))

        ax.scatter(rows[0][5], 0.1, s=5, c='black')
        ax.text(row[5], 0.15, text, ha="center", va="bottom", fontsize=7.0, bbox=bbox)

    fig.suptitle(row[0])
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)     # Add space at bottom
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator())   
    #ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.DayLocator())   
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%Y\n%m')) 
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])

plt.show()
```

This would show one ID as:

[image: matplotlib scatter plot]

Comment: As I said for each individual user I want graph like this, but this for multiple user.

Comment: Thank you, Let me try out and I will reach out to you in case any problem.

Comment: What if I want to remove Recordtype ? what changes I should do ?

Comment: Replace the text line with `text = ', '.join([row[2] for row in rows])`

Comment: I want to display date also . one more thing, Since you are displaying the data by comma separated and on single bar, but I want it in a stacked like first  is C then below it C1 kind of

Comment: I tried above and solve the problem but the text is overlapping on each other. and also i still can't solve the problem each date display .

Comment: I've updated it to show how you could stack the output, and have also included the day of the month.